# How can I check SMTP server is alive with Python?

Tags: python

I want to check if an email exists with Python. I can check the format and DNS records correctly, but how can I check if the SMTP server is alive?

I tried a few libraries because I didn't want to use APIs. For example [validate_email](https://github.com/karolyi/py3-validate-email)

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email(email_address='sample@sample.com', check_format=True, check_dns=True, dns_timeout=10, check_smtp=True, smtp_timeout=10, smtp_debug=False)
print(is_valid)
```

But I still couldn't check the SMTP server.

Comment: Please post the code that you have already tried, It will help helper to write you a new program or by checking your code then can suggest what to do with that! Try edit and do that

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/ for check server is up/down and ports are open.

Comment: You should try to add more content than just a link. The link could break, and this answer would be useless if that happened. Also, try to provide syntax as well.

Comment: Hi Vinicius and Welcome to SO, maybe can help you this article about How to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer